# arima xreg argument error caused by column name in data frame

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I'm trying to run the code below and I'm getting the error below.  The code uses auto.arima from the forecast package to determine and fit an arima model to some data.  It's also using regressors in the xreg argument.  I think the names of two of the columns in the xreg might be the issue, but I'm not sure why.  The names of the columns are like "structure.c.NA..NA..211L.."  They're the output of a function.  If I run auto.arima without those columns in the xreg argument it seems to do fine.  Any tips on how to solve this are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
auto.arima(df2_comb[1:100,names(df2_comb)=='ECDD'], xreg = df2_comb[,names(df2_comb)!='ECDD'][1:100,names(df2_comb[,!names(df2_comb)%in%c('ECDD','order_dts')])])
```

Error:

```
Error in auto.arima(df2_comb[1:100, names(df2_comb) == "ECDD"], xreg = df2_comb[,  : 
  xreg should be a numeric matrix or vector
```

Data:

```
dput(df2_comb[1:100,])
structure(list(ECDD = c(319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 
319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 
319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 198, 142, 254, 178, 97, 113, 116, 
109, 127, 102, 99, 107, 109, 89, 101, 106, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 
319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 257, 169, 191, 115, 
121, 121, 108, 110, 105, 93, 103, 93, 107, 99, 113, 319.4, 319.4, 
319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 237, 
106, 108, 108, 117, 99, 105, 108, 100, 93, 88, 105, 95, 109, 
319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 319.4, 192, 
169, 319.4, 136, 108, 163, 136, 114, 116), order_dts = c("2017-12-31 09:00:00", 
"2017-12-31 10:00:00", "2017-12-31 11:00:00", "2017-12-31 12:00:00", 
"2017-12-31 13:00:00", "2017-12-31 14:00:00", "2017-12-31 15:00:00", 
"2017-12-31 16:00:00", "2017-12-31 17:00:00", "2017-12-31 18:00:00", 
"2017-12-31 19:00:00", "2017-12-31 20:00:00", "2017-12-31 21:00:00", 
"2017-12-31 22:00:00", "2017-12-31 23:00:00", "2018-01-01 00:00:00", 
"2018-01-01 01:00:00", "2018-01-01 02:00:00", "2018-01-01 03:00:00", 
"2018-01-01 04:00:00", "2018-01-01 05:00:00", "2018-01-01 06:00:00", 
"2018-01-01 07:00:00", "2018-01-01 08:00:00", "2018-01-01 09:00:00", 
"2018-01-01 10:00:00", "2018-01-01 11:00:00", "2018-01-01 12:00:00", 
"2018-01-01 13:00:00", "2018-01-01 14:00:00", "2018-01-01 15:00:00", 
"2018-01-01 16:00:00", "2018-01-01 17:00:00", "2018-01-01 18:00:00", 
"2018-01-01 19:00:00", "2018-01-01 20:00:00", "2018-01-01 21:00:00", 
"2018-01-01 22:00:00", "2018-01-01 23:00:00", "2018-01-02 00:00:00", 
"2018-01-02 01:00:00", "2018-01-02 02:00:00", "2018-01-02 03:00:00", 
"2018-01-02 04:00:00", "2018-01-02 05:00:00", "2018-01-02 06:00:00", 
"2018-01-02 07:00:00", "2018-01-02 08:00:00", "2018-01-02 09:00:00", 
"2018-01-02 10:00:00", "2018-01-02 11:00:00", "2018-01-02 12:00:00", 
"2018-01-02 13:00:00", "2018-01-02 14:00:00", "2018-01-02 15:00:00", 
"2018-01-02 16:00:00", "2018-01-02 17:00:00", "2018-01-02 18:00:00", 
"2018-01-02 19:00:00", "2018-01-02 20:00:00", "2018-01-02 21:00:00", 
"2018-01-02 22:00:00", "2018-01-02 23:00:00", "2018-01-03 00:00:00", 
"2018-01-03 01:00:00", "2018-01-03 02:00:00", "2018-01-03 03:00:00", 
"2018-01-03 04:00:00", "2018-01-03 05:00:00", "2018-01-03 06:00:00", 
"2018-01-03 07:00:00", "2018-01-03 08:00:00", "2018-01-03 09:00:00", 
"2018-01-03 10:00:00", "2018-01-03 11:00:00", "2018-01-03 12:00:00", 
"2018-01-03 13:00:00", "2018-01-03 14:00:00", "2018-01-03 15:00:00", 
"2018-01-03 16:00:00", "2018-01-03 17:00:00", "2018-01-03 18:00:00", 
"2018-01-03 19:00:00", "2018-01-03 20:00:00", "2018-01-03 21:00:00", 
"2018-01-03 22:00:00", "2018-01-03 23:00:00", "2018-01-04 00:00:00", 
"2018-01-04 01:00:00", "2018-01-04 02:00:00", "2018-01-04 03:00:00", 
"2018-01-04 04:00:00", "2018-01-04 05:00:00", "2018-01-04 06:00:00", 
"2018-01-04 07:00:00", "2018-01-04 08:00:00", "2018-01-04 09:00:00", 
"2018-01-04 10:00:00", "2018-01-04 11:00:00", "2018-01-04 12:00:00"
), structure.c.NA..NA..211L..211L..211L..211L..211L..211L..211L.. = c(0, 
0, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 
211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 131, 94, 168, 117, 64, 75, 
77, 72, 84, 67, 65, 71, 72, 59, 67, 70, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 
211, 211, 211, 211, 170, 112, 126, 76, 80, 80, 71, 73, 69, 61, 
68, 61, 71, 65, 75, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 
211, 156, 70, 71, 71, 77, 65, 69, 71, 66, 61, 58, 69, 63, 72, 
211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 211, 127, 112, 211, 90, 71, 
108, 90), structure.c.NA..NA..NA..NA..48L..48L..48L..48L..48L..48L..48L.. = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 30, 21, 38, 27, 15, 17, 17, 16, 19, 15, 
15, 16, 16, 13, 15, 16, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 39, 
25, 29, 17, 18, 18, 16, 16, 16, 14, 15, 14, 16, 15, 17, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 36, 16, 16, 16, 18, 15, 16, 16, 
15, 14, 13, 16, 14, 16, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 29, 25, 
48, 20, 16), S1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0), S2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
), S3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
    S4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), S5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S6 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), S7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S9 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), S10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), S12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S13 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S14 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), S15 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S16 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), S17 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S18 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S19 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), S20 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S21 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), S22 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S23 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(forecast)
## it works
auto.arima(df2_comb[1:100,names(df2_comb)=='ECDD'], xreg = as.matrix(df2_comb[,names(df2_comb)!='ECDD'][1:100,names(df2_comb[,!names(df2_comb)%in%c('ECDD','order_dts')])]))
## it fails
colnames(df2_comb)[3]<- "structure_211"
colnames(df2_comb)[4]<- "structure_48"
auto.arima(df2_comb[1:100,names(df2_comb)=='ECDD'], xreg = df2_comb[,names(df2_comb)!='ECDD'][1:100,names(df2_comb[,!names(df2_comb)%in%c('ECDD','order_dts')])])
```

It is no related with the names, as you can see if you change them, fails in the same fashion.
But is you use `xreg` `as.matrix` it should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you!  That did the trick.  This same code worked fine in the past and worked fine on my mac, but had issues on a pc.  Do you know if there was a change made recently to the forecast package?